# How to access richTextBox of another instance of my program?

Tags: c#

I'm making a Text Editor program. When clicking the Open button, the program will automatically do following steps:

1. Open another instance of current program
2. Load text into the richTextBox of that instance

But the problem is: How can I load the text into the richTextBox of another instance of my program? Instance, not form, so this is difficult.

Comment: define a service that join those 2 instances... or crete a channel over a socket to share the data....

Comment: Why not open that second instance with an argument telling it what to load into the text box?

Comment: File path as command line argument for the other instance for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line arguments for example.

The entry point of your application could look like that:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filepath = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : null;

    if (filepath != null)
    {
        // load your text to control
    }
}
```

And you could call the other instance with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, filepath);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm noob to C#. Can you write the full code, please? I can't figure how to put argument in C# and make it work. By default, my program will load nothing

Comment: See `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath, filepath);`. Here the `filepath` is your argument.